# How to pass hash data in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, dynamic-programming, view-components

I'm facing the issue

```
undefined local variable or method `student_details'
```

while trying to write a Ruby method that gives dynamic data to display in the browser. I've used view_component gem.
My "component.rb" file looks like following:

```
module Shared
  module Student
    class Component < ViewComponent::Base
      def initialize(title:)
        @title = title
      end
      student_details = {name: "John Doe", course: "Rails Development", student_id: "1"}
    end
  end
end
```

And "component.html.erb" looks as:

```
<div class="font-montserrat flex flex-col bg-white text-shadow-none">  
  <%= student_details.student_id %>
  <%= student_details.name %>
  <%= student_details.course %>
</div>
```

Comment: You're just assigning the local variable `student_details` which is instantly garbage collected. Read the readme... https://viewcomponent.org/

Answer (score 0):

The data is only accessible via instance variables (`@var`) or ruby methods (`def method`). You could do this with the variable:

```rb
module Shared
  module Student
    class Component < ViewComponent::Base
      def initialize(title:)
        @title = title
        @student_details = {name: "John Doe", course: "Rails Development", student_id: "1"}

      end
    end
  end
end
```

or this with a method

```
module Shared
  module Student
    class Component < ViewComponent::Base
      def initialize(title:)
        @title = title
      end

      def student_details
        {name: "John Doe", course: "Rails Development", student_id: "1"}
      end
    end
  end
end
```